# DataGridTemplateColumn EditingElementStyle equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf

I am coding the following piece of code and it is looking like it is functional. However once I get a validation error it stays even if the validation error has been corrected. I am using validation at row level as well as at cell level on my `DataGridTextColumn` using the `EditingElementStyle` parameter but this can't be used in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Is there an equivalent that I can use as I am not sure how to proceed. Below is a sample of my code showing one of my `DataGridTextColumns` and my `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Instrument" MinWidth="140">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >                                    
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PRODUCTNO, Mode=TwoWay}"/>                                 
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{StaticResource TestList}">
            <ComboBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="PRODUCTNO" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ValidationRules:IntegerValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.Text>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>

<dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="BATCH No." Width="100" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}">
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="BATCHNO">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:StringValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</dg:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try out what [*this*](http://www.varigence.com/Blog/Post/17) person did. The code snippets on the page don't seem to work, but what he suggests is to rather use a customised **DataGridTextColumn** instead of **DataGridTemplateColumn**. I'm going to try that and I'll update my answer when (or if) it works.